# Selenium-IDE open action not interpreting variable

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am new to Selenium IDE and have come across an issue where I can "echo" a stored variable but it does not work as target to the "open" action.

For example:

```
store | TESTING  | myVar

echo  | ${myVar} |

open  | ${myVar} |
```

Produces the output:

```
1.Trying to execute store on TESTING with value myVar... Success
echo: TESTING
3.Trying to execute open on ${myVar}... Success
```

But the browser url generated is:

```
http://imac:8888/$%7BmyVar%7D
```

Rather than:

```
http://imac:8888/TESTING
```

I cannot find any documentation suggesting this limitation of variables in the "open" action.

I am using:

Chrome version Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit)
MacOS HighSierra version 10.13.4

Any help appreciated as Selenium looks like a potentially great solution to help me prototype and test.